# Downloaded files not launching in Chrome - Why?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, browser

Strange behavior in Chrome, in OSX Mountain Lion.

After I download a file, it appears in the bottom bar of the browser, normally I can just click on the file and it launches. Or click the small arrow to the right and 'reveal in finder'. However, both of those options are not working anymore. And I can't seem to figure out why.

I've flushed the cache, cookies, etc.. Restarted. And to no avail.

Any idea what may be going on here?

Comment: linux for me.. EL6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar problem. Files were donwloaded in 'Downloads' but when right-clicking on 'Show in Folder' it showed the Desktop.

I did the following to make it work as normal.

In Chrome, go to **Preferences**, then go to the bottom and click on **Advanced**, then go to the **Download section**.

[image]
Double check if the path is correct. (if not, then that might have been your problem).

Then set the 'Ask where to save each file before downloading' on **On**

Go to a website and download and image or go to your Webmail and download an attachment.
Save the file to the right folder (in my case 'Downloads')

Then go back to the settings and set the 'Ask where to save each file before downloading' back to **Off**

Then the first will still go wrong, but the second and following times it will download it in the correct folder.

Versions:

- macOS Mojave 10.14
- Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

You said you flushed the cache... have you cleared the Download folder (and the download history)?

I've seen issues on Windows where launching downloads progressively becomes slower as the download location and history fill up.

Comment: yes I have. It's the strange behavior of not being able to click on the files and having them launch that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Chrome is up to date and make sure the file has finished downloading before trying to open it.

If neither of these work, try re-installing Chrome and if that fails, just open it with Finder, by default it will be in your download folder.